# call to undefined factory() method in zend query caching mechanism php

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework

I am trying to implement caching the query results with the help of zend caching in php

for which i m using following code

```
<?php
include 'zend/library/Zend/cache.php';
$frontendOptions = array(
   ‘lifetime’ => 10,
   ‘automatic_serialization’ => true
);
$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => 'tmp/'
);
$cache = Zend_Server_Cache::factory(‘Core’, ‘File’, $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
$id = ‘rs’;
$start_time = microtime(true);
if(!($data = $cache->load($id)))
{
    echo "Not found in Cache<br />";
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db('dbname');
    $query ='select * from tablename';
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $cache->save($data);
}
else
{
        echo "Running from Cache<br />";
}
//echo ‘<pre>’;
//print_r($data);
//echo ‘</pre>’;
//echo sprintf(microtime(true) – $start_time);
?>
```

I am getting an error on 13 line which says that call to undefined zend_server_cache::factory() method.

zend_server_cache file is present in my zend server folder.but factory method is not available in that.Thats why i m getting an error at that line.Please guide if there is any way to implement factory method in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `Zend_Server_Cache::factory()`, try with `Zend_Cache::factory()`

Comment: but the classname which I m using is Zend_Server_Cache,not the Zend_Cache.SO will that make a difference sir?

Comment: There is not factory method in Zend_Server_Cache class. And you include cache.php wich have Zend_Cache class wich have factory method

Comment: I have two cache.php files right now with me for different versions.but both doesnot have factory method. So without method,it will throw an error.ryt sir? hw can we overcome this

Comment: What is your ZF version?

Comment: OK, my answer is about ZF1... I don't know well ZF2, but I think your are wrong about call factory method, if I'm not mistaken, it is rather Zend/Server/Cache instead of Zend_Server_Cache. Good Luck.

Comment: i googled about cache.php file for zend framework.I find that this file is found under zend/library/zend/cache.php,but i find this file in zend/library/zend/server/cache.php,That might make a difference.is it?And if yes.then if i use ZF1,will I found this factory method in cache.php file there that i m looking for?I m sorry if questionaire is long but i m stuck with this problem

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. :( With your example (in the question) try with ZF1, and change the include path (if the library of ZF1 is not in the same folder) and change Zend_Server_Cache::factory() by Zend_Cache::factory(). If you want to use ZF2, I'm sorry, but I can't answer.

Comment: k.k.Will Zend_Cache file in ZF1 folder be having factory method.I will try with ZF1 then.can u please share any ZF1 download link..

Comment: Thanks a ton man.It solved the error by removing server from classname.now i m getting an error which says call to a member function load() on a non object.can u please help me out or shud i raise separate question

Comment: Great. :) If my answer resolve your question, please, validate it. for the new error, you should post a new question, it's more 
readable.

Comment: Thank's and if I can answer to your new question, I do it. :)